# Why || = not compiled such that if we use [] or not, in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

why this difference:

```
class Foo
  getTest: ->
    @test ||= 42
```

compiled to:

```
return this.test || (this.test = 42);
```

different of

```
class Foo
  getTest: ->
    @test['bar'] ||= 42
```

is compiled in :

```
var _base;
return (_base = this.test)['bar'] || (_base['bar'] = 42);
```

what is the usefulness of this variable "_base"?!

```
return this.test['bar'] || (this.test['bar'] = 42);
```

is a good way too, no?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two broad categories of structures that `||=` needs to consider:

```
simple_expr  ||= x
complex_expr ||= x
```

A *simple expression* would be something like `@test`: (probably) no side effects and (probably) no performance penalty to evaluating it twice.

A *complex expression* would be anything else: `@test['x']`, `@test(11).pancakes`, ... Complex expression could have side effects or could be expensive so you only want to evaluate them once.

Now consider how many times `expr1` is evaluated in:

```
expr1 || (expr1 = expr2)
```

Sometimes `expr1` will be evaluated twice so CoffeeScript is stashing as much of `expr1` as it can in `_base` to avoid the expense and possible side effects of evaluating `expr1` twice.

You might also notice that for simple expressions, that only possible thing to stash in `_base` is the whole expression itself. I suspect that they're actually defaulting to considering all expressions complex and then leaving out `_base` when it turns out that there's nothing to stash in it.

Comment: I agree if expression are complexe, like a function, but this.foo.bar? Hum... not convinced

Comment: You can look at [`cacheReference`](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/1.8.0/src/nodes.coffee#L520) and `isComplex` in the source if you need to convince yourself. With things like `@foo.bar` it is, presumably, a question of how clever they want to be with their "is it complex?" checks; also, `a.b.c` isn't necessarily free.